# Error in SQL Syntax when creating simple foreign key reference

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

Here's my script:

```
create table Country
(
CountryId int primary key,
Name varchar(255)
);

create table Person
(
PersonId int primary key,
Name varchar(255),
FOREIGN KEY (CountryId) references Country(CountryId)
);
```

I'm transitioning from MS SQL and trying to get a grasp on MySQL and starting off with my typical hello world of Person->Country relationship to get a feel for foreign keys.

I'm getting this error on PHPMyAdmin:

> SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE Person(
>
> PersonId INT PRIMARY KEY , Name VARCHAR( 255 ) , FOREIGN KEY (
>   CountryId ) REFERENCES Country( CountryId ) );
>
> MySQL said:
>
> 1072 - Key column 'CountryId' doesn't exist in table

What newbie mistake am I making here?

Comment: You changed the question after I answered! The new error is due to your second table not having a 'CountryId' field.

Comment: @MattHumphrey: So I have to declare the field explicitly in another line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you had not created the column in Person that would be used in the foreign key, thus, `Key column 'CountryId' doesn't exist in table`. Here's how you'd do it:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    PersonId INT PRIMARY KEY , 
    Name VARCHAR( 255 ) , 
    CountryId int,
    FOREIGN KEY ( CountryId ) REFERENCES Country( CountryId )
);
```

Comment: Can I write the creation and foreign key binding on the same line similar to MSSQL?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can research here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html